# I want to make a tree of parents only in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, cte, recursive, tree

My table in the database

[image]

How can I get my result as `Where child = 'chl1'`?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the tables as text rather than images? So anyone that answers it doesn't have to type this all out first

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #t(child varchar(4), parent varchar(4))

insert into #t values ('ch1','ch')
insert into #t values ('ch','c1')
insert into #t values ('ch','c2')
insert into #t values ('bsd','chl1')
insert into #t values ('chl2','ch')
insert into #t values ('c1','c')

select * from #t


;WITH ch AS 
( 
--initialization 
SELECT child, parent
FROM #t 
WHERE child ='ch1'

UNION ALL 

--recursive execution 
SELECT #t.child, #t.parent
FROM #t 
JOIN ch on ch.parent = #t.child
) 
SELECT * FROM ch
```

One of the solutions for hierarchical queries is a CTE recursively joined to itself. In the example before, we run initialization query:

```
SELECT child, parent FROM #t WHERE child ='ch1'
```

Then join it to itself (ch) using join condition `ch.parent = #t.child` until no records found or until the `MAXRECURSION` limit is reached. Default value is 100 but it could be overridden up to 32767 via an `OPTION (MAXRECURSION xxx)` hint. Zero can also be specified, meaning 'no limit'.

For background, see [Recursive Queries using Common Table Expressions (CTE) in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1520/recursive-queries-using-common-table-expressions-cte-in-sql-server/) by Edwin Sarmiento.

Comment: There are an error : The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Comment: When I use option max recursion select statement result showing all child to all parents.  I need to select all parents only